# Can Orange read in IF...THEN text format rule file and use it to score another dataset?

Tags: python, orange

I am wondering if Orange can read in a text format rule file and use it to score another dataset. For example, a rule.txt file was previously created in Orange through rule_to_string function and contains rules in this IF...THEN  format:
"IF sex=['female'] AND status=['first'] THEN survived=yes". Can Orange read in the rule.txt file and use it to score a test.csv dataset? Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no function to do this. Apparently nobody ever needed it.

You can do it yourself, but if you know some Python it should be easier to test a list of rules without using Orange.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and information!